# Website subdirectory permission?

Tags: html, web-services, apache, permissions, acl

I just new to website develop. I got a simple question as following:

1. Assuming I have an `index.html` under: `http:www.myWebsite.com/A/B/C/index.html`, and I want to people be able to see this page (`index.html`), however, NOT able to access:

   - `myWebsite.com/A/B/C/`
   - `myWebsite.com/A/B/`
   - `myWebsite.com/A/`
     What sure I do? "
2. "What if in addition, I have another `index.html` page under `myWebsite.com/A/B/index.html`, again I want to people be able to access both of those two pages (under `C` and under `B`), but NOT following:

   - `myWebsite.com/A/B/C/`
   - `myWebsite.com/A/B/`
   - `myWebsite.com/A/`
     What sure I do"
3. In general, what is the access control policy for multi-directory on website?

(By default, my server running on linux, apache, and all files under `/var/www/html`.)

Thank you!!!!!

---

Sorry for the confuse. When I mean can NOT see (access), I mean forbidden. What I'm try to say here is, sometimes, if you tpye `myWebsite.com/A/B/C/test.html` you will see whatever on `test.html`, however, if you just type `myWebsite.com/A/B/C/`, you see `forbidden` message. That's what I mean you can see or cannot see...

Comment: You mean you want to disable displaying the `index of/` directory indexes? - http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/

Comment: I modified the question, sorry for the confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the site.conf (Normally httpd.conf if you have not changed it.) find the site VirutalHost contanier for the site.

If you see

"DirectoryIndex" delete that line.

IE:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DirectoryIndex index.htm (**REMOVE THIS LINE**)
</VirtualHost>
```

Also in the httpd.conf look for the line

```
DirectoryIndex and remove index.htm or whatever else you want to remove.
```

Thank should do it.

It might be good to also search for index.htm to make sure there are no other instances.

Also make sure you restart apache.

Comment: I modified the question, sorry for confuse.